# How to say properly translate "circulation"?

Tags: translation, usage

I know that 通风 means to ventilate, but how does one say circulation? Two specific sentences I'm having trouble translating are:

> He wanted to save energy, so he turned on the *circulation* fan instead of the air conditioning

vs.

> The new coins that the government approved go into *circulation* today.

I do not believe that circulation is the same in these sentences.

Comment: In the first example, is that any different from, say, a ceiling fan? I'm not familiar with the term "circulation fan", although it's easy to imagine what it means.

Comment: @StumpJoePete Apparently more modern air conditioning systems have a circulation feature that change out the indoor air and turn on ~25% of the time, but it runs through the buildings vents, so it's like air conditioning but much more efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

circulation fan (空气)循环风扇

money circulation 货币流通

blood curculation 血液循环

the circulation of news, information, rumours, etc 新闻/信息/谣言的传播

She's been ill but now she's back in circulation. 她一直生病, 但现在又重新参加社交活动了.

a newspaper with a (daily) circulation of more than one million （日）销售量超过一百万份的报纸

circulation figures 销售数字.

Answer (score 0):

Circulation stresses more on the whole process of gas of liquor flow, while ventilate decline to the meaning of in and out. 
And circulation is more abstract compared with ventilate, so it get a wider usage range.